# How can i compile a c++ library for ARM on windows

Tags: c++, arm, windows-phone-8

I have a library in c++ and for the time being there are a bug in CMAKE / or missing feature for using the Visual Studio Arm Generator.

What other options do i have to compile the library for ARM such i can use it in my c++ runtime components for windows 8 phone projects.

I would like to build the library and then link against it from the Runtime Component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft and Kitware have enabled CMake support for Windows Phone and Windows Store apps. Can you please try your project using this version of CMake?
http://cmakems.codeplex.com/ 
Very soon, the contribution will be available in the official CMake repository as well

Comment: Marked it as answer since this was what i was waiting for in the first place, i forgot to return to the question after cmake 3.0 was released

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the phone and the PC have different processors and need different assembly instructions.

You will need to tell Visual Studio that the target platform of your library is ARM processor.  You will need two library files, one for the PC and one for the ARM.

At work, we use two different compilers, Visual Studio for the PC and IAR EW for the ARM platform.  We are currently sharing some source code files between them, but not object or executable libraries.

Comment: The problem is that Visual Studio Arm Generator do not work right now with cmake. This means I can not get my c++ library compiled for arm, such it can be linked against from the Runtime Component. Its the telling Visual Studio that the target is ARM that gives alot of problems. I will try searching for IAR EW and see if i can find something there.

Answer (score 0):

can you be more specific to the error you are getting... ?

my guess is that your CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN file is errorprone..

try compiling the same library natively using cmake ... if it is working well, then you have to write your CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN file overriding the compiler and/or library search path in toolchain file...

P.S cmake do provide visual studio arm generator....

http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.9/cmake.html#gen:VisualStudio11ARM

Comment: A few searched here on Stackoverflow you will find that the Arm Generator are not working. (Might be fixed for next version of cmake). I came to the conclussion that cmake do not set the platform toolset properly. I kinda gave up as i had a hard time understanding the error and things that needed to be configured. Instead i just creates Windows Phone Shared Dlls in VS and include the source code.